# How much of a mock is a Mockito mock?

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, mockito

This is a serious question, I promise.  I've spent the last 2 hours reading as many definitions of Mock that I could find and none explain this to me.

I've got a class I want to test and that class requires a mapper class as part of it's primary constructor:

```
open class PoiListViewModel @Inject constructor(
        private val mapper: PoiMapper
) : ViewModel() {
```

In my unit test I have the following code:

```
//Mock objects needed to instantiate the class under test
@Mock lateinit var mapper: PoiMapper

// Class being tested
lateinit var poiListViewModel: PoiListViewModel

@Before
fun setup() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)
    poiListViewModel = PoiListViewModel(mapper)
}
```

My question to you all smart developers is, what exactly is a mock?  And specifically how much of my original class does it replicate?

I'll tell you my assumed definition. A mock is a fake stand-in class that stands in for my real class, *but that it does nothing except keep track of what method calls get sent to it.*  If I want the mock to have any functionality I need to stub that functionality in.

At least that's my ignorant view of mocks.  But I'm apparently wront because in my unit test, my "mock" mapper class seems to be an *actual* mapper class.  If I debug my unit test I see it walk through all the code of my mapper class.  I see it returning converted data.

Here's the mapper class code (if it matters):

```
open class PoiMapper @Inject constructor() {

    fun mockTest(num: Int): Int{
        return num *23
    }

    fun mapToPresentation(domainModel: Poi_Domain): Poi_Presentation {

        var test = 3
        var results = mockTest(test)

        return Poi_Presentation(domainModel.id,domainModel.name,domainModel.description,
                domainModel.img_url,domainModel.latitude,domainModel.longitude,domainModel.imgFocalpointX,
                domainModel.imgFocalpointY,domainModel.collection,domainModel.collectionPosition,
                domainModel.release,domainModel.stampText)
    }
}
```

Can someone explain it to me, how much of a mock is a Mockito mock?  Did I instantiate the mocks incorrectly?  Can someone give me a better way to think of mocks so I can wrap my head around all this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your understanding of mocks is correct. You're bumping into Kotlin's final-by-default behavior, as an implementation detail of Mockito.**

Mockito mocks (as distinct from Mockito spies) are defined to take the place of your class instance. Unless you've stubbed them to return otherwise, they record all interactions and return default dummy values (zero, an empty string, an empty list, null, etc). You can confirm that they collaborated correctly with your system-under-test by stubbing return values (`when`/`thenReturn`), stubbing specific behaviors for methods (`when`/`thenAnswer`), or by checking that certain methods were called (`verify`) and retrieving the specific instances they were called with (ArgumentCaptor).

*Under the hood*, Mockito achieves this by generating a subclass of the class you're mocking, and overriding all methods to delegate to Mockito's internal handler. This is what gives Mockito the power to override the behavior silently: Your system-under-test thinks it's calling your dependency, but your code is using Java's virtual method dispatch to override your dependency's behavior.

Here's the trick: Java methods are virtual by default, unless you mark them `final`. In Kotlin, functions are [closed by default, unless you mark them `open`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#overriding-methods). (I'm going to keep calling them `final`, because that's the definition at play in the JVM or Android Dexer, which is reading the bytecode that Kotlin generates anyway.) When the virtual machine is sure of a reference's type based on static typing, and you're calling a `final` method, the compiler is allowed to [inline that implementation's code (JLS 8.4.3.3)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.3.3) because you've asserted that the method cannot be overridden and any code that tries to override it will fail at compilation. *Mockito's generated code isn't compiled this way, and Mockito can't detect this case.*

In your case, `mapToPresentation` is not `open`, so the compiler sees it as `final` and does not keep the virtual method dispatch that would let Mockito override the behavior. Your definition of mocking is right, and your code would be right, except that Kotlin is closed-by-default where Java is open-by-default. Besides, you really do rely on the function being `open`, because you'd like it to be called with a different implementation than the one in the function.

Trivially, you could just make all functions `open` that you intend to override, or use [Mockito 2.1+'s built-in feature to mock final methods](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki/What%27s-new-in-Mockito-2#unmockable). However, as a general best practice you want an object that behaves like a PoiMapper even if it doesn't follow your specific PoiMapper implementation. That might be a good reason for an interface/impl split, such that your class PoiListViewModel takes a PoiMapper interface. In production you can provide a PoiMapperImpl as you have, but Mockito can generate an arbitrary implementation of the PoiMapper interface without worrying about whether PoiMapperImpl and its functions are open or closed.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the annotation

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
```

to your test class?